# How To Set Startup Route In ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, routes, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET core app startup route is set as:

```
/api/values
```

I want to change this startup route to be:

```
/
```

Looking through the documentation there is lots of specification on route constraints but I'm not sure I see how to set the route that gets run on startup...

It's calling the wrong controller on startup. If I remove the controller (ValueController), I get a 404. Where is it specified to use this controller at runtime?

I'm seeing hope in the hidden launchSettings.json but editing

```
http://localhost:5000/api/value
```

to

```
http://localhost:5000/
```

does not help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adam Weitzman is right, but you can also switch it using Visual Studio's GUI.

1. Right-click on project in Solution Explorer
2. Click Properties
3. Go to Debug tab
4. Check the `Launch URL` checkbox and set the URL you want. Leave the text box empty to launch the root URL

[image: Launch URL setting]

Answer (score 4):

It's in `Properties/launchSettings.json`

the field to change is:

```
profiles.IISExpress.launchUrl
```

Comment: I'd rather edit the JSON than use the UI any day ;-)