# Using default route without Home controller (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, just a question on default route. there is an application only has one controller `FruitController` and there is no HomeController.

And in the startup.cs, it is using:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

But how can the web app still be directed to the `Fruit/index` when I run the web app? The template sets the default controller to `Home`, so it should be directed to `Home/Index`, which should cause a "Not Found" error.

Comment: I am not sure if you are having a problem changing `{controller=Home}` to `{controller=Fruit}` or what exactly is the problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , I didn't change that even though I can change that. My question is, I have no home controller, so why the ASP.NET MVC considers "Fruit" to replace the "Home" controller

Comment: Do you mean that if you just hit debug, it goes straight to FruitController? Is the route `/` or `/Fruit`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes  goes straight to FruitController, its '/Fruit'

Comment: Hmmm, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42352449/2141621) the route that VS is using by default

Comment: @slowjams It is the default parameters (Home/Index) in ASP.NET and if you want Fruit instead of Home as default you just modify it.

Comment: If you start debugging when Fruit controller or view is active in code window  then you will see that page, but if you go to root of your site (ie: http://localhost:xxxxx where xxxxx is the port number) you'll see Home/Index page. Is this your case?

Comment: @slowjams I tried to replicate the issue but not able to replicate it. Could you please add some more information with code snippets?