# Set starting route in a visual studio blazor project

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a server side 3.0.100 blazor project in VS2019.

I have several pages.  I would like it if while I was debugging i could start a non-default route/page for debugging purposes.

What I've tried on the project properties debug tab:

1) Setting the Launch browser relative path.  If i set this, to say "equipmentlist", the app starts at localhost:44325/equipmentlist but displays the root route.  If i then navigate to the equipmentlist page, the url changes to localhost:44325/equipmentlist/equipmentlist and the correct content displays.

2) Setting the App URL: this has the same behavior as 1

I'd like to save myself extra clicks every time i click debug.

Edit:
The "Launch browser" setting changes the address that displays when the browser launches, but the content displayed is still the default route.

i.e.  localhost:44325/equipmentlist/ is displayed in the browser address bar but it still shows the content from the "/" page.  I have to navigate to localhost:44325/equipmentlist/equipmentlist to see the content required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Set Startup Route In ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350067/how-to-set-startup-route-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to modify `launchSettings.json`  file under the `Properties` node of the project to set `launchUrl` for `IIS Express` profile, like

```
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "equipmentlist",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
//...
```

Comment: @safetyOtter I understand and reproduce your problem.My solution does resolve it when I create a new blazor server app and add `"launchUrl": "counter"` to set startup  page as counter component.Could you also try in a new project?

Comment: You're right it does work with a new project.  There's something in mine that's breaking it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

You have two way to do it :

The easiest one is to open the project properties and set **Launch browser** URL in the **Debug** panel :

[image]

This'll update your *Properties\launchSettings,json* file for you. But you can manually edit it of course.

```
{
...
  "profiles": {
...
    "Aguacongas.TheIdServer.BlazorApp": {
...
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "equipmentlist",
...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @safetyOtter Actualy it do the job, you ask to navigate to equipmentlist and it navigate to equipmentlist. If you want navigate to equipmentlist/equipmentlist set equipmentlist/equipmentlist. The issue you have now is probably in <base href> but this not the same question.

Comment: It's navigating to equipmentlist but not showing equipmentlist's content. It's showing the content from "/"

Comment: You have a routing issue or your <base href> is not well configured

Comment: And this not the same question, open a new one.

Comment: It's literally the same question "Set starting route in a visual studio blazor project." What you describe changes what displays in the address bar but it does not change the route.

Comment: But routing is code,not VS stuff ! You said: "I would like it if while I was debugging i could start a non-default route/page for debugging purposes.", That's respond to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and stumbled opon your question. Maybe someone else will and finds here some help or explanation for this:

---

After some tests it seemed, that IIS Express wasn't able to route proberly.
Without using IIS Express, everything was working as intended.

After some tests and searching I could resolve this problem by deleting the .vs folder.

---

In this folder, you can find the applicationhost.config. This file controls the IIS Express applications for your project.

In it you can find a knote for application. Here is defined, which Application Pool will be used and where the physical files are located.
If you change "applicationUrl" in the "launchSettings.json", a new knote will be added and causing this problem. Even if you change "applicationUrl" back, the knote will not disappear!

```
<site name="Webapplication1" id="3">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Webapplication1 AppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\source\repos\Webapplication1" />
    </application>
    <application path="/equipmentlist" applicationPool="equipmentlist AppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\source\repos\Webapplication1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62461:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44381:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
```

To solve this, simply delete the wrong knote and you should be fine.